# I keep getting Status Code 400 when using googleCloudRunner package?

Tags: r, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to automate my R script in Google Cloud. To do this I'm using the `googleCloudRunner` package. I've set up my environment using the built in package wizard and i get all green ticks. However when I run `cr_setup_test()` to make sure everything is working I get this error

```
── Attempting Docker deployment on Cloud Build via cr_deploy_docker() ──

ℹ 2024-02-07 00:24:10.267285 > Dockerfile found in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/googleCloudRunner/example/ - using it and ignoring dockerfile argument

── # Deploy docker build for image: gcr.io/ftsl-413522/example ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

── # Uploading /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library/googleCloudRunner/example/ to gs://ftsl-dart/example.tar.gz ───────────────────────
ℹ 2024-02-07 00:24:10.309621 > Tarring files in tmpdir:
• api.R
• Dockerfile
• server.R
ℹ 2024-02-07 00:24:10.358367 > Uploading example.tar.gz to ftsl-dart/example.tar.gz
ℹ 2024-02-07 00:24:10.369507 > File size detected as  1.1 Kb
ℹ 2024-02-07 00:24:10.475586 > StorageSource available for builds in directory: /workspace/deploy
ℹ 2024-02-07 00:24:10.493655 > See ?cr_buildstep_source_move for a buildstep to move files into /workspace/
ℹ 2024-02-07 00:24:10.872573 > Request Status Code:  400
Error in `abort_http()`:
! http_400 Precondition check failed.
```

any help on this would be great!

this is the code, again i used the googleCloudRunner wizard to set it up so i dont know how much help this'll be

```
cr_setup_test()
ℹ Perform deployments to test your setup is working. Takes around 5mins.  ESC or 0 to skip.
✔ Successfully auto-authenticated via /Users/AO/Documents/R Projects/FTSL/ftsl-413522-61cf96665c02.json
✔ Validated authentication in GCE_AUTH_FILE
Select which deployments to test 

1: All tests
2: Cloud Build - Docker
3: Cloud Run - plumber API with Pub/Sub
4: Cloud Build - R script
5: Cloud Scheduler - R script

Selection: 3
```